# Bypass Jenkins job executor limit

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline job that runs on Master node and executes some stages on other nodes. When I execute a lot of this pipeline, It fills entirely the Master node job limit, but those jobs don't take any resource but only wait stages to finish.

Is there a way to bypass node executor limit for specific pipelines or should I handle it another way?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Why does it run on the master though if it doesn't do anything other than waiting?

Comment: Post your pipeline ...

Comment: @tkausl there are some stages at the beginning, in the middle and at the end that performs some synchronization and some treatments that needs to be done on master node, based on slave nodes work

Comment: @IanW sorry but it's too big and not really relevant I think? It's something like divide-and-conquer algorithm

Comment: Of you are exceeding the controller limit, it's relevant. We run dozens/100s concurrent pipelines (1000+ runs/day), never hit a limit. Share the pipeline structure at least.